# How can we add before after css code dynamically with vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to solve a problem which I actually never faced. I am trying apply dynamic color from my data inside v-for loop. Now normal css properties are easily appliable. I need to apply css for `after`. I tried

```
<div class="_tmln_shdl_crd_itm" v-for="(t, i) in timeLine" v-if="timeLine.length">
    <div class="_tmln_shdl_itm_lft">
        <p :style="`color:${t.color}`">{{t.time}}</p> // THIS WORKS
    </div>
    <style>
        ._tmln_shdl_itm_r8_one h4:after{ // TRIED TO WRITE CSS WITH FOR LOOP BUT FAILED :D
                color: t.color
         }
    </style>
<div>
```

So how can I make it work for `._tmln_shdl_itm_r8_one h4:after` ?

Any solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style you create in the loop creates CSS for the same selector every time. The browser only has one applicable CSS styling for this selector.
With the same selector, the newest CSS wins and is applied. This is [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) ("When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element.").

You can create classes dynamically:

```
<div class="_tmln_shdl_crd_itm" v-for="(t, i) in timeLine" v-if="timeLine.length">
    <div :class="`_tmln_shdl_itm_lft _tmln_shdl_itm_lft-${i}`">
        <h4>{{ t.time }}</h4>
    </div>
    <style>
        ._tmln_shdl_itm_lft-{{ i }} h4:after{
            color: {{ t.color }};
        }
    </style>
<div>
```

Something like that should work. Making the class dynamic with `._tmln_shdl_itm_lft-{{ i }}` makes the magic work.
This also adds a lot of CSS fluff to the page which is probably not what you want in a live environment.

**Remarks:**

- You also should output `t.color` like this (probably just a mistake in your example):
  `color: {{ t.color }};`
- There is also no `h4` tag in your example code that the CSS could apply for, but that's probably somewhere else in your page.. hopefully?